# MongoClient, connect with '@' in password

Tags: php-mongodb

I've been trying to experiment with MongoDb, and when I run the script to connect, it can't because the password uses the `@` symbol.

To connect to MongoDb

`mongodb://username:password@localhost`

But as my password to connect to MongoDb uses the `@` symbol, it can't connect due to the `@` symbol.

***For example;***

`new MongoClient("mongodb://mongo:p@assword@localhost);`

Will throw the following error;

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: assword!@localhost:27017: Couldn't get host info for assword!@localhost'`

As you can see, it thinks the first `@` in the password is the seperator for password and host.

**Is there a way to connect, and allow the `@` symbol in the password when using [MongoClient](https://www.php.net/mongoclient)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php you can pass the username and password as an options array

`new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017", array("username" => "joe", "password" => "test"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this code. Just pass your input as per dynamic value.

```
try {
            $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://HOST:" . MNG_PORT, array(
                "username" => MNG_USER,
                "password" => MNG_PWD
            )); // connect local Mongo
            $db = $m->selectDB("DBNAME"); // select DB
            $collection = $db->collections; // connect to collection
        } catch ( MongoConnectionException $e ) {
            echo 'Couldn\'t connect to mongodb, is the "mongo" process running?';
            exit();
        }
```